# C++ Ignores While Loop Condition

Tags: c++, while-loop

Recently, I created a text-based RPG in C++ and am now trying to incorporate a simple pathfinding algorithm. I have tested the algorithm itself and found that it works, however the while loop condition in the function started being ignored when I tried to incorporate it into the RPG. Here's my code:

```
    int Strategy::path(char (&map)[25][100], int current_y, int current_x, int Target_x, int Target_y)
{
    int i;
    int n;
    bool up=false;
    bool down=false;
    bool left=false;
    bool right=false;
    while (map[Target_y-1][Target_x]!='_'&&map[Target_y-1][Target_x]!='-'&&map[Target_y-1][Target_x]!='='&&map[Target_y+1][Target_x]!='_'&&map[Target_y+1][Target_x]!='-'&&map[Target_y+1][Target_x]!='='&&map[Target_y][Target_x-1]!='_'&&map[Target_y][Target_x-1]!='-'&&map[Target_y][Target_x-1]!='='&&map[Target_y][Target_x+1]!='_'&&map[Target_y][Target_x+1]!='-'&&map[Target_y][Target_x+1]!='=')
    {
        bool f=false;
        int m=0;
        system("cls");
        printf("Time left: %i\n", time);
        int x;
        int y;
        using namespace std;
        for (y = 0; y<25; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x<100; x++)
            {
                cout << map[y][x];
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (current_y > 0 && map[current_y - 1][current_x] ==' ')
        {
            map[current_y - 1][current_x] = '-';
        }
        if (current_y < 25 && map[current_y + 1][current_x] ==' ')
        {
            map[current_y + 1][current_x] = '-';
        }
        if (current_x > 0 && map[current_y][current_x - 1] ==' ')
        {
            map[current_y][current_x - 1] = '-';
        }
        if (current_x<100 && map[current_y][current_x + 1] ==' ')
        {
            map[current_y][current_x + 1] = '-';
        }
        map[current_y][current_x] = '=';
        for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
            {
                if (map[i][n] == '_')
                {
                    current_y = i;
                    current_x = n;
                    f=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (f==true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
            {
                if (map[i][n] == '-')
                {
                    map[i][n] = '_';
                    m++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (m==0)
        {
            return 4;
        }
    }
    bool r=false;
    while (true)
    {
        int d=rand()%4;
        if (map[Target_y + 1][Target_x] == '_' && d==0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
                {
                    if (map[i][n] == '-'||map[i][n]=='_'||map[i][n]=='=')
                    {
                        map[i][n] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else if (map[Target_y - 1][Target_x] == '_' && d==1)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
                {
                    if (map[i][n] == '-'||map[i][n]=='_'||map[i][n]=='=')
                    {
                        map[i][n] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
        else if (map[Target_y][Target_x+1] == '_' && d==2)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
                {
                    if (map[i][n] == '-'||map[i][n]=='_'||map[i][n]=='=')
                    {
                        map[i][n] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
            return 2;
        }

        else if (map[Target_y][Target_x-1] == '_' && d==3)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
                {
                    if (map[i][n] == '-'||map[i][n]=='_'||map[i][n]=='=')
                    {
                        map[i][n] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To say its difficult to reason about that while condition is an understatement. Perhaps break it out into a function of its own?

Comment: Consider breaking that really long unreadable expression up into pieces, then use a debugger to see which pieces are incorrect and adjust your code to match your expectation. You might also read through [mcve] and consider fixing up your question. You might also consider using a helper function for this, especially since you're almost certain to go outside the bounds of your array without more checking for edge cases.

Comment: If i had to guess, I'd say it's a problem of your initialization of the array prior to the while loop. There's virtually zero chance it's actually the compiler. I suggest creating a function to print out your array and call that before the while loop (for debugging) just to make sure it's set up how you expect it to be. Btw, there's no use in passing an array by reference in this context. Arrays always pass by "reference" anyway because they are implicitly converted to pointers.

Comment: Some debugging tips when it comes to if statements as mentioned before split it into a different function or break it up using white space also organizing it with parenthesis can make sure it executes as expected. and also as mentioned above print out the statement to see if it evaluates as you would expect it to.

Comment: What's the first `Target_x` and `Target_y`? If the compiler can prove that you always access `map` out of range it can do whatever it likes with your whole program

Answer (score 0):

As all the other comments pointed out, you definitely **should** use a function in your while-condition. This really is an unreadable expression.

Maybe this will help you:

```
bool conditionValid(char (&map)[25][100], int target_x, int target_y)
{
  char c='0';
  for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i)
  {
    switch(i)
    {
      case 0: c = map[target_y-1][target_x]; break; //check the first character
      case 1: c = map[target_y+1][target_x]; break; //check the second character
      case 2: c = map[target_y][target_x-1]; break; //check the third character
      case 3: c = map[target_y][target_x+1]; break; //check the forth character
    }

    switch(c)
    {
      case '_': std::cout << "aborting ... c" << i << "= " << c << std::endl; return false;
      case '-': std::cout << "aborting ... c" << i << "= " << c << std::endl; return false;
      case '=': std::cout << "aborting ... c" << i << "= " << c << std::endl; return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int Strategy::path(char (&map)[25][100], int current_y, int current_x, int Target_x, int Target_y)
{
    int i;
    int n;
    bool up=false;
    bool down=false;
    bool left=false;
    bool right=false;
    while (conditionValid(map, Target_x, Target_y))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As soon as you understand, why your loop aborted, you can remove the `std::cout`'s